# Undefined method `each' for #<User:

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.1
Ruby 2.0

Credential.rb

```
class Credential < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :user

    validates :name, :login, :password, presence: true

    attr_accessor :encryption_key

    attr_encrypted :login, key: :encryption_key
    attr_encrypted :password, key: :encryption_key
end
```

User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :credentials

  def you
    "You are <b>#{email}</b>"
  end
end
```

CredentialsController.rb

```
class CredentialsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    @credential = current_user.credentials.new
    @credential.encryption_key = session[:master_key]
    @credential.update(credential_params)

    if @credential.save
      redirect_to credential_path(@credential), notice: "Password entry created successfully."
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end
```

The line:

```
@credential.update(credential_params)
```

throws an exception

```
undefined method 'each' for #<User:0x4de4f58>
```

Comment: A Credential `has_many :users` and a User `has_many :credentials`. If you want a many-to-many relationship, this isn't how you do it. You need a `belongs_to :user` or `belongs_to :credential` on the Model with the foreign_key. Also, you have a typo. It's `has_many :users` not `has_many user`.

Comment: Silly mistake ) Add a reply I will mark it!

Comment: Did that fix your error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to edit your associations. You have credentials that `has_many :user` and users that `has_many :credentials`. The one with the foreign key should be a `belongs_to` not `has_many`. If you're attempting to make a many-to-many relationship, then either use `has_many_and_belongs_to` or a join table. Further, it should be `has_many :users` and not `has_many :user`. That should resolve your error.